# 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade fails -

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I tried to "do-release-upgrade" from 18.04 to 20.04, but the upgrade fails.

```
Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'. 

Restoring original system state
Aborting
```

Logs show:

https://pastebin.com/CFXJ908H  (apt.log)
https://pastebin.com/EYJGFUU2  (main.log)

Any insight on what may be going wrong?

Comment: Does your system have ppa's installed?

Comment: Yes - most are us.archive.ubuntu

Comment: Those are not ppa's.

Comment: I did a sudo apt policy and it listed a list of PPA's

Comment: Synaptic shows I have six "other software" PPA's installed

Comment: If you have ppa's on your system (I am not sure if you do or not) the error message you listed in the question tells you what to do: remove them before doing the upgrade.

Comment: Synaptic manager shows a tab for "other software". In this location there are 5 packages installed. Removing these will cost me functionality I use all of the time (xrdp, plex, etc.). I may have to just wait until 18.04 EOL and then do a clean install.

Comment: You can add the ppa back in after the upgrade if it's available in the new release. It just screws up the process of upgrading.

Comment: thanks - I'll give this a shot. To be clear - I should remove packages which are shown in "other software" - correct?

Comment: You should remove all unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu -- as instructed by the error

Comment: ... then I might as well do a clean install? It's probably not worth the effort to upgrade to 20.04 and just stick with 18.04. 18.04 works great and will be maintained under LTS for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

For me the x11-utils was the problem. Run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove x11-utils
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

And you should be done.